# How to attach mongrel.rb to initializer in Redmine?

Tags: ruby, redmine, mongrel

I have Windows Server 2008 R2 with MySQL and Subversion installed separately. Just to mention that it is also having IIS.

I have completed all steps as described on here:
http://www.richardnichols.net/2009/09/1-minute-guide-installing-redmine-on-windows/

I'm not able to login to the Redmine. It just doesn't login after entering username & password and stays on the page "Your're being redirected".  I've found the solution to the problem which asks to attach the file to initializes.  I just don't know how to do it?

Here is the corresponding link: http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/28918?r=29107

And what other steps need to take to get it started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the mongrel.rb in the initializer folder inside Redmine Folder.